# Bidirectional Benjamin-Ono vs Benjamin-ono

Tags: fluid-dynamics, differential-equations, integrable-systems

I am a mathematician and not a physicist, and I am trying to physically understand the difference between the model described by the [Benjamin-Ono equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benjamin%E2%80%93Ono_equation) and the model described by the [bidirectional Benjamin-Ono equation](https://www.google.com/search?as_q=bidirectional+benjamin+ono+equation).

$$(BO): \partial_{t} u=H \partial_{x}^{2} u-\partial_{x}\left(u^{2}\right)$$
where $H$ is the Hilbert transform : $H f(x) \stackrel{\text { def }}{=} \frac{1}{\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x-\xi} f(\xi) \mathrm{d} \xi.$

$$ (2BO): \partial_t u+\partial_{x}\left[\frac{1}{2} u^{2}+\frac{g}{2} \partial_{x} H u\right]=0$$

Comment: I don't think there are necessarily any "physics" associated with the bidirectional Benjamin-Ono equation.  It seems to have been created by Abanov, Bettelheim, and Wiegmann as a basically mathematical exercise, not based on any physical motivation (in contrast to the B-O equation).  What's more, calling it "bidirectional" is misleading in an important way, because it implies that the equation (which is not, by the way, what appears in the question) overcomes the greatest difficultly of the B-O equation, which is that it only supports general soliton propagation in a single direction....

Comment: The "bidirectional" B-O does not overcome that key weakness, since it makes the domain of the function $u$ into a ring, rather than covering the full $x$-axis.  A true bidirectional generalization of B-O would described propagation of waves and solitons from $x=-\infty$ to $x=+\infty$ as well as $x=+\infty$ to $x=-\infty$.  Instead the equation set out by Abanov, Bettelheim, and Wiegmann describes clockwise or counterclockwise propagation on a ring in the Argand plane.